# Downgrade Windows 10 via command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 is BSD'ing within 30 seconds of startup, and in safe mode if I click the Settings section for Update & Security to navigate to rollback, it just closes the Window.

Is there any way to initiate the rollback from a command line?  Or access the downgrade option more directly without going through that section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downgrade option is available in the recovery menu. Boot into windows, then hold shift while pressing restart to boot into the recovery menu. From here, through one of the submenu's where you can perform a clean install of windows 10, you can also revert to the old version of windows, if the folder still exists on your computer. (Microsoft claims you have 30 days before it removes that folder)

Comment: Thanks, it was somewhat vaguely labelled as "Go Back to Previous Build" which sounded more like going to a earlier build version of windows 10, but in fact did roll me back to Windows 7