# Go back to windows 7 from cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am updated to windows 10 from windows 7 and now my computer is stuck in infinite loop of recovery and i cant use windows so i want to go back to windows 7 (i lost my windows 7 license) from the troubleshooting command line

Comment: Duplicate question here>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1005492/downgrade-windows-10-via-command-line

Comment: Your Windows 7 license if printed on the CoA sticker on your device.